# add default route on boot

Tags: 10.04, boot, default, networking

I'm trying to add a default route on my ppp0 connection, I want the default route points to that connection. I tried to add it in `/etc/rc.local` but I don't think that is the right place to do so. I would like to know where is the right place to accomplish this.

Comment: What kind of network interface are you talking about? eth, wireless, ... ?

Comment: ethernet, i need to add this "route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" but when the machine shutdown or restart  it loses..

Answer (score 4):

The right place should be the file `/etc/network/interfaces`. You add a line like:

```
up route add default gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

The IP address is the one of your default gateway and the last entry is the device name of your device.

Comment: here is the las think i tried.
The problem is that my conexion is ppp0, my eth0 is my LAN, and the eth1 is the ISP
conexion... i put in /etc/network/interfaces
"up route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev eth1"
also try with
"up route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0"
and didnt work.. in both cases when i run netstat -nr i get this:
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 U 0 0 0 ppp

Comment: if i run in command line "route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ppp0" Works! after run
netstat -nr i get
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 ppp0

Comment: Are you using Network Manager? It'll overwrite this setting.

Answer (score 3):

Already long time ago, but none of the above described solutions worked for me. I finally found the solution in the comments in the ip-up file under the /etc/ppp directory in Ubuntu.

I created a script in the `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d` directory, where I put the `route add` command in.

The script is picked up automatically after the pptp connection was created. It works like a charm.

Comment: Still works in 2019, even on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Network Manager, you can add a route via the Configure VPN... menu option under the networking widget. Then on the VPN, click on edit for the VPN you need to add a route to. Then under IPV4 settings, change Method to Automatic VPN. Then click on routes and add your route there (eg network 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.20) where the gateway is the VPN server you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

Your default route for your primary interface?  This should be done by default if you're using DHCP. If you have a statically configured interface, you'll need to add a stanza to `/etc/network/interfaces`. Assuming your interface is `eth0` and network is `192.168.1.0/24`:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0 

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.123
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

(Obviously these numbers would be adjusted for your network.)

Add this to `/etc/network/interfaces` and that's it.  Now if you want a static route that is NOT your *default* route, that is different.

Comment: Is there a cli method / file to edit that isn't going to be immediately overwritten by NetworkManager?